# Exceptional case for $\delta$-method

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Recently, I have learned the $\delta$-method and I am thinking about an example.

Suppose $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables with $Var(X_1)=1$ and $EX_1=c$. Let $\overline{X}_n=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Then, if we take $g(x)=x^{-1}$ and $c\neq 0$, then by CLT and $\delta$-method, $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n^{-1}-c^{1})\overset{D}{\rightarrow}N(0,1/c^4)$, since $g^{'}(c)=-c^{-2}$. But what if c=0 in this case? Should I use other method to solve this problem?

Any advice would be appreicated!

Comment: When $c = 0$, $\bar{X}_n \to c = 0$ almost surely by SLLN, then $|\bar{X}_n^{-1}|$ will be arbitrarily large and the result here may not apply

Comment: You might want to look at the [Reciprocal normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use continuous mapping theorem in this case.

Suppose $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta)\overset{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$, and we are interested in $g(\hat{\theta})-g(\theta)$. In the proof of delta method, we first apply a Taylor expansion around $g(\theta)$, which requires $g(\cdot)$ exists at $\theta$.

In a more interesting example (in my opinion), where $\hat{\theta}=(\hat{\theta}_{1},\hat{\theta}_{2})^{\top}$, and $\theta=(0,\theta_{2})^{\top}$,

- If $\theta_{2}\neq0$, delta method gives results like $\sqrt{n}\hat{\theta}_{1}/\hat{\theta}_{2}\overset{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})$, hence $\hat{\theta}_{1}/\hat{\theta}_{2}$ is $O_{p}(n^{-1/2})$.
- If $\theta_{2}=0$, continuous mapping theorem gives $\hat{\theta}_{1}/\hat{\theta}_{2}\overset{d}{\to}\mathrm{Cauchy}$, hence $\hat{\theta}_{1}/\hat{\theta}_{2}$ is $O_{p}(1)$.